# Shortest possible distance between this point and this line?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, coordinate-systems

What is the shortest distance between the point $(1,8,-4)$ and the line that is given by the equations,

$-2/5+(1/5)x=-2+(1/2)y=-3-(1/2)z$?

My guess it that it has to do with a straight line.. Because the shortest distance between tho points A and B is a straight line. My idea was to implement the dot product or the projection formula in some way. I could find a point on the line by plugging in for example, $x=2$, obtaining an answer and solving for $y$ and $z$. This gets me a point on the line $(2,4,-6)$. I could find the distance between the point on the line and the point outside the line with the assistance of the distance formula, which assetains me, $\sqrt{21}$. Now, I would wish to be able to project $\sqrt{21}$ on the line but I struggle. This is where I need help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What projection formula do you know?

Comment: @orlp Typo-error.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Comment: Ok, so do that.

Comment: How? I do not know to project sqrt(21) orthogonally on the given equation, do you?

Answer (score 1):

If you can write te equation of the line in vector form, there is already a formula how to calculate this distance. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation).
So we write $\vec r=\vec r_0+\vec n t$. If we write this by components we have $$\begin{align}x&=x_0+n_x t\\y&=y_0+n_y t\\z&=z_0+n_z t\end{align}$$
You can now explicitly calculate $t$ from every equation, and you get $$\frac{x-x_0}{n_x}=\frac{y-y_0}{n_y}=\frac{z-z_0}{n_z}$$
It should be now trivial to calculate $\vec r_0$ and $\vec n$ by just identifying the coefficients from your equation with the above formula.  Now use the expression on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation) to get the perpendicular vector, and then you get the distance by taking the norm.

Comment: I got this, r=r(0)+nt=e(-2:-4:6)+t(5:2:-2). Now, I am wondering how to continue.

Comment: Just plug those values into the formula in the link above

Comment: I am sorry! I just can not get it right. Could you assist me, please?

Comment: With respect to $\vec r_0$, a point on the line is at $t\vec n$. The point you want to project on the line is at $(1,8,-4)-\vec r_0$. What's the length of the projection? How can you write it using the dot product? Now if you know the length of the projection, you can find out where the point is projected on the line. Then just subtract the vectors, and get the length